# How to assign a value to sqlparameter NULL values without checking for null or 0?

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand, dbnull

The following check is needed to check for null values. is there a way i can do it directly?

```
 if(node.ID==0)
 {
   cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
 }
  else
  {
    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = node.ID;
  }
```

is there way we can cicumvent this check and a design by which we can avoid this repetitive check for each value? (by the way its just a logic that 0 to be interpreted as NULL for my case but am asking the same about nullable objects like string too)

Comment: You could use the ternary operator (? :) to write it all in one lime, would that help?

Comment: Note that it would be a pretty different answer for nullable types (reference or nullable value types). Is there any reason you haven't made your `ID` property a `Nullable<int>` or whatever?

Comment: How if you accidentally write into the database what you don't really want? You may appreciate a prior check is required then. It's sometimes not a bad thing when an exception fires.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was not sure if Nullable<int> is safe to use (not familiar with it) in case someone else uses it later, but I Will try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For nullable types, I'd just use an extension method:

```
public static object CoalesceNullToDBNull(this object input)
{
    return input == null ? DBNull.Value : input;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
cmd.Parameters["Foo"].Value = someExpression.CoalesceNullToDBNull();
```

(You could give it a shorter name, of course.)

That won't help for your case though, because you're trying to coalesce a non-null value to null. I would personally consider redesigning your model - use a nullable type for values which can be null, rather than using a magic number. However, you *could* still use a generic extension method:

```
public static object CoalesceDefaultToDBNull<T>(this T input)
{
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(input, default(T))
        ? DBNull.Value : (object) input;
}
```

That will convert `0`, `'\0'`, `false`, `null` etc to `DBNull.Value`. You'd have to use that with extreme care though, as I assume there are plenty of places where a 0 should really be a 0.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = node.ID == 0 ? (object)DBNull.Value : node.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this regularly, try putting the check inside of a method.

For instance:

```
// ...
SetFormattedValue(ref cmd, node.ID);
// ...

private void SetFormattedValue(ref IDBCommand cmd, int id) // IDBCommand - or whatever your command type is
{
    if(node.ID==0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = node.ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `??` operator:

```
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = node.ID ?? (object)DBNull.Value
```